# Getting error while running cordova build android phonegap

Tags: eclipse, cordova, android-studio, sdk, phonegap-build

I'm getting so many errors in phonegap

```
#cordova build android
```

> Error: Please install Android target: "android-23".
>    Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: /home/deb/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
>   You will require:
>
> 1. "SDK Platform" for android-23
> 2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
> 3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)

I have checked my cordova android requirements. Requirements check results for android:

```
#cordova requirements android
Java JDK: installed .
Android SDK: installed 
Android target: not installed 
Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
Gradle: not installed 
Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
```

Looked here: /home/deb/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper

in `my ~/.profile` file I've added these lines

```
#~/.profile
if [ -d "$HOME/opt/gradle" ]; then
    export GRADLE_HOME="$HOME/opt/gradle"
    PATH="$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin"
fi
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/deb/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="/home/deb/sdk/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem after lots of research and if you are facing the same problem it could help you.

First, [install Gradle](http://exponential.io/blog/2015/03/30/install-gradle-on-ubuntu-linux/) if you haven't. Don't set up the env for now so just follow the steps before `gedit ~/.profile` this command

Install ant if you haven't `sudo apt-get install ant`
Install android sdk if you haven't. 
 https://gist.github.com/wenzhixin/43cf3ce909c24948c6e7

We'll avoid set path we'll do it later. Now check your env by printenv in case you tried earlier unset the variables.

```
 unset ANDROID_HOME
```

Whatever variable you have used just unset them and type to clear the paths:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Now we're good to go. Paste this:

```
gedit ~/.zshrc
```

Please note that you have to use your path to android sdk for mine it's `$home/sdk/android-sdk-linux`

`$home` means `/home/username/`

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/sdk/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platforms:$PATH
export GRADLE_HOME=$HOME/opt/gradle
PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
export ANT_HOME=/usr/bin/ant
export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin
source ~/.zshrc
```

Now if you type cordova requirements android you will get error of target not installed!

We'll solve it here. Use your path to sdk then type the command

```
sudo ln -s /home/deb/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/./android /usr/local/bin/android
```

Now if you type android in your terminal, Android SDK manager will open.

Comment: Please learn [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).